# Read csv file from website return java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I am trying to read the csv file from the URL. But I get java.io.FileNotFoundException. The URL works on browser. Please help.
Below is my csv reading code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {


        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new URL("http://prod2.riskval.com/site/table.csv​").openStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String data;
            try {
                data = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to be the problem. I tried with another file and it worked like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

InputStream input = null;

URL url = new URL("http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String data;

data = in.readLine();
System.out.println(data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your URL has hidden character, I just tried copy pasting the same URL in the browser and it gave me 404. as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome), when you copy the text from MS Word or WordPad or similar editor your get these `%E2%80%8B` characters which indicated end of line.

Just copy paste the URL in sublime or any other text editor which show hidden characters and you should see something like this

> http://prod2.riskval.com/site/table.csv%E2%80%8B

Comment: Thank you so much! It works after changing UTF-8 to MS950.

Comment: @KristenChang Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your read problem. Please study it.

```
package tttttttttttttttt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ss {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        InputStream input = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            input = new URL("http://www.google.com").openStream();
            System.err.println(input);
            System.err.println(input.available());
            System.err.println(input.markSupported());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print("Captured " + br);
    }
}
```