# Laravel : How to link a button with a secure url?

Tags: php, laravel, url, href

I have tried to add secure url to href I have got some weird characters after the link.

what I have done:

```
<a href='https://example.com/request-access'>request</a>
```

What I got :

https://example.com/request-access%E2%80%8E

I am wondering why these characters has been added, I know it is a selly question

Can anyone help me, Please.

Comment: Did you copy that URL from some editor? Looks like some EOL char from MS Word or similar, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{!! secure_url('https://example.com/request-access')!!}"></a>
```

or 
`<a href="{!! secure_url('request-access')!!}"></a>`

this should solve the problem