# Anchor tag do not redirects properly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had created new Instagram social icon in the footer by editing "social-icon.php" file. My code is:

```
<li class="et-social-icon et-social-instagram">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ashvinibhave/‎" class="icon">
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Instagram', 'Divi' ); ?>
       </span>
    </a>
 </li>
```

That link redirects to "https://www.instagram.com/ashvinibhave/%E2%80%8E"

Comment: You must have a plugin or something interfering with your link.

Comment: You likely copy&pasted that into your code yourself ... it’s a [Left-to-Right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark), see also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome Re-type that part, so that only the actual characters are present, then it will work. Get yourself an editor/IDE that can either display substitution characters for such “invisible characters”, or a HEX editor, so that you can check what is actually there in such cases.

Comment: Agreed with @CBroe this must be the case .... I tried to remove last forward slash from your provided url and it works .. so must be something wrong with copy paste or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i just pasted it from official website of yours its working fine man
But whenever i pasted it from your its sends me to that link you are referring to