# Angular add extra variable on Img at end %E2%80%8B

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
 http://myimage.png%E2%80%8B
```

I have just copy paste this img url but it added some wiered data on end and image does not show . but on code it looks perfect .

I have tried something in Angular like

```
var imageSafeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.imageLink);
this.imageLink = imageSafeUrl['changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity'];
```

but still it adds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress putting %E2%80%8E at the end of my url, howcome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome)

Answer (score 1):

The data is url encoded so it can be typed safely in an address bar and interpreted by the browser/server

> %E2 = â
>   %80 = `
>   %8B = ‹

A table to help you interpret the encoded characters is available at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

So together you have copied [http://myimage.pngâ](http://myimage.png%C3%A2)`‹

Answer (score 0):

Added "?" after link now Extra data is set as query parameter

```
<a title="GreenPop" href="http://myimage.png?" >
```