# Angular REST requests adds characters which breaks request

Tags: angular, rest, request

I have an issue which did'nt happen before. When setting up a URL Angular seems to add a lot of characters to the URL thus breaking the URL.

The URL request is combined using interpolation:

```
const url = `${this.restUrl}​​​​​​​professionals/${userId}​​​​​​​/skills`;
```

When loggin the line before sending it, it looks as follows:

```
https://localhost:5001/​​​​​​​professionals/693450e6-1621-496a-b80f-eb6572867842​​​​​​​/skills
```

But when the request is made the URL is:

```
https://localhost:5001/%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bprofessionals/693450e6-1621-496a-b80f-eb6572867842%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B/skills
```

How can I make sure that the URL is not changed by Angular

Comment: looks like a copy/paste problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868916/angular-add-extra-variable-on-img-at-end-e2808b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like codebrane said its copy/paste problem.

i did copy and test the url and it get encoded the same way as you

i rewrote it and tested it , now it works fine
i suggest you rewrite the parts you did copy/paste and retry !