# Unwanted extra characters in S3 Key while uploading files for aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have my following shell script which I am using to upload files to my s3 bucket.

```
#!/bin/sh

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$KEY_ID"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$KEY_SECRET"

echo "[INFO] AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID - $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
echo "[INFO] AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY - $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"

S3_URL="s3://mybucket/uploads"

aws s3 cp ../data.pdf       $S3_URL/data.pdf
aws s3 cp ../data.html.zip  $S3_URL/data.html.zip

echo "[INFO] Uploaded Successfully"
echo ""
```

When I run this script, the files get uploaded to S3 bucket. However, I see some extra characters at the end of the key name.

Here is the screenshot from my S3 browser UI,

[image]

> Can somebody tell me why these characters are coming up automatically, when I didnt intend them to come.
>
> How can I get rid of these?
>
> Also, this is creating issues for my download service which is not able to read these files and gets Key not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have some invisible UTF-8 code inserted in your script.

See: [Wordpress putting %E2%80%8E at the end of my url, howcome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10342012/174777)

Also, see web search: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%25e2%2580%258b

Make sure that you are using a real text editor (not something like MS Word). There should be something like a *Zap Gremlins* command that can remove bad characters.

Or, just delete and re-type (don't copy/paste) the lines with `aws s3 cp` in them.

Comment: Thanks John. I was able to get this working finally. Seems like using variables substitution is causing this. I changed to use the the original aws s3 command and that worked.