# Hi change my request url on runtime, how to fix this bug?

Tags: reactjs, url, axios

Hi i development react app use axios and sometime my api request url change on runtime but this is my enum object.frezee variables.

For example my url :

> http://www.myapi.com/api/v1/question/getQuestions

but change my url :

> http://www.myapi.com/api/v1/question%E2%80%8B/getQuestions

after that return not found req error.
why change my url and how to fix this url ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13822119/815600
With this, copy paste your link in a notepad and paste it back in IDE.