# How to Remove "Percentage" (%) from Permanent URL?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I can't remove all the unwanted stuff (%) from this permanent URL:
https://nopassiveincome.com/digital%e2%80%8c-%e2%80%8cevents%e2%80%8c-%e2%80%8cmetrics%e2%80%8c/
[image]

It should be simply this, as I see in my WordPress dashboard:
[https://nopassiveincome.com/digital‌-‌events‌-‌metrics‌/](https://nopassiveincome.com/digital%E2%80%8C-%E2%80%8Cevents%E2%80%8C-%E2%80%8Cmetrics%E2%80%8C/)

It never happened to me in 10 years of blogging...LOL

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: It's not unwanted. They're encoded characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress putting %E2%80%8E at the end of my url, howcome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your wp post or pages, wherever this file is located in particular, and quick edit the post. Change the slug to digital-events-metrics. In the future, don't use any special characters in your URLs. Just use a space and it should come across as dashes.

Comment: Make sure the space is a single space, not double or triple space.

Answer (score 0):

You are using non-common characters and they get encoded, nothing you can do about it, because that's how the internet works.

If you don't want them, don't use special characters.

For example your blankspace:

```
‌
```

It's not a normal 1-byte blankspace. It's a `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` blankspace with 3 bytes: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128