# Fetch url with javascript property inserted, but UTF-8 characters keeps appearing in the console causing 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

this is the main problem:

```
: decodeURI(`https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries​/${countryCode}`);
```

in console i get this:

```
App.js:59 GET https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries%E2%80%8B/AI 404
```

the url somehow changes only upon doing the fetch(url), the countryCode when i console.log seems fine

there are these random letters **%E2%80%8B** inside the url that i dont want how do i remove it?

```
const onCountryChange = async (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value;
    console.log('country info', countryCode) 

    const url = countryCode === 'worldwide' ? "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all" : decodeURI(`https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries​/${countryCode}`);
    
    await fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())

    .then(data => {
      setCountry(countryCode);
      setCountryInfo(data);

    })
  };
```

Comment: Don't you want encodeURI not decodeURI before making the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%E2%80%8B` is the correct URL encoding for [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). The code you've shared contains an invisible space right before the slash:

```
countries​/${countryCode}
        ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to clean the `event.target.value` before you use it as a parameter in the URL.

If you do a simple regex clean on the input text, it should be solved:

```
const countryCode = event.target.value.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```

Similar question: [Wordpress putting %E2%80%8E at the end of my url, howcome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome)

Comment: hi thanks for answering, the countryCode is fine however, the error only appears when on fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())