# In Nuxt js project axios auto encoding url

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Original url is  `click​/verifytoken​/`, but it is requesting to
 `click%E2%80%8B/verifytoken%E2%80%8B/` this url, I didn't add
 `'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'`, and it shows  `404 Not Found` what is the reason?

Comment: which axios have you used in your project ,original `axios` or `@nuxtjs/axios`?

Comment: using @nuxt js/axios

Comment: show your `plugins/axios.js` and `nuxt.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

When copy and pasted, invisible spaces were present in the route you provided. [Did you copy that route from somewhere else, like MS Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome)

If you write the URL yourself from scratch, you won't have this issue.