# Weird Axios Post Behavior. Introducing weird strings at the end of the request URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I am trying to call an API endpoint using axios but axios adds some strings on the end of the request url.

I have an endpoint which is

```
https://api.com/api/Inbound/RemoveCartItem
```

But what happens is that the request URL is transformed into this mess when the function is called

```
https://api.com/api/Outbound/RemoveCartItem%E2%80%8B
```

I have been trying to figure this out what is causing the weird strings to appear on the end part of the request URL.

Here is my function calling the URL

```
const removeInboundCartItem = async function(item) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://api.com/api/Inbound/RemoveCartItem`,
      mapper.mapStocklistToCart(item)
    );
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return [];
  }
};
```

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342012/wordpress-putting-e2808e-at-the-end-of-my-url-howcome

Comment: Checking on it @Radeanu. But it doesn't seem to work with me at the moment. I am going through all of the suggested solution at the moment

Comment: None of the suggested solutions there have worked with me @Radeanu. I still have the same issue